# Unable to start libre office from terminal

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, raspberry-pi, libreoffice

I need to start libre offices impress via SSH on various raspberry pies, each displaying a set of slides on its own screen.

Now my problem is that, when I run `loimpress --show file.odp` it states *unknown option* and suggests I should use `--help`, which again produces a **segmentation fault** (same with plain `libreoffice --help`).

When using `man loimpress`, the `--show` option is listed.

I'm on a Raspberry Pi B and an updated Raspbian.

How can I start Libre Office Impress from a terminal, directly in presentation mode?

Comment: Did you ssh into your RPie using the `-x` option?

Comment: No, intentionally. The presentation should run on the remote display, attached to the RPie I ssh to. The problem is that already testing the command locally fails as described.

Comment: I could be wrong, but as far as I know, you can't take control of the remote display (more correctly, of the remote active session). It shouldn't segfault though. Try starting the Impress from the raspberry over ssh (with -x or -Y). If it always has to start, you could run it from some .rc file.

Comment: Does `DISPLAY=:0 loimpress --show file.odp` work? Can you run other programs by setting the DISPLAY variable before the command?

Comment: The problem is that `loimpress --show file.odp` doesn't work - the libre office version is unusable with parameters, even segfaults.